# Google Script - File Download

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google Script to write a simple program for my marketing class.

Our project is to sell a song via QR codes and limit the number of downloads. The keeping track part is already written (SpreadsheetApp makes it simple). All I need to do is serve the file for download. Is there a way to do this?

If not, can I at least embed a link to an external server where the MP3 is hosted? I tried using app.add(app.createHTML('a file')); but Caja seems to be filtering the A tag. Am  I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think Caja comes into play when you are writing an UI App (assuming this based on the fact that you're using app.add )

Using UIApp, you can use app.createAnchor() to create a hyperlink to an external file.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I always forget that Anchor is another name for link. :P Sorry about the dumb question.